# Excel: Making a formula to discount total cost

Tags: excel, if-statement

We are making a spreadsheet for a company, and I figured out all the other numbers but the final total after discount I am struggling to come up with a Formula

For example: discount can either be 10% or 0%, then we have to take the total before the discount first, then for the last one we have to figure out the total after the discount

An example would be a discount 10% Total before discount of 1,860, then need to find a fourmla to find the total after discount

Any Ideas or takes?

Comment: Can you present the code or what you have done and some simple data for us to look at so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `1860` in `A1` cell. Then use below formula to `B1` cell.

```
=A1-A1*10%
```

[image]

If you want to make discount from a calculated value then use below formula.

```
=SUM(A1:A3)-SUM(A1:A3)*10%
```

Here your values are in `A1:A3` and you want to make sum first then discount `10%` from that summation. With <kbd>Microsoft365</kbd> you can try `LET()` formula.

[image]

```
=LET(x,SUM(A1:A3),x-x*10%)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the percentage out in a separate cell to make it easy to change, like so:

```
=A1*(1-(B1/100))
```

Where B1 contains 10 representing 10%. You can put $B$1 if the discount is constant or B2 onwards contains the relevant values.